# How to make images as an anchor in the navbar bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Does anyone know how I can make images as an anchor in the navbar? I'm using bootstrap and my images are wrapped in `<a>`, but after clicking on it nothing happens. I want to link my LinkedIn profile to the LinkedIn image and my GitHub to the github image. Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar w-100 navbar-expand">

      <!-- github and linkedin icons -->

      <a class=" navbar-brand  github pull-right navbar-right nav-link" id='navLink' href="https://github.com/alessandraburckhalter" target="_blank"><img src="/images/github-removebg-preview.png" width="30"></a> 

      <a class="navbar-brand linkedin pull-right navbar-right " href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alessandra-burckhalter/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/png-clipart-computer-icons-social-media-linkedin-social-network-social-media-text-trademark-removebg-preview.png" width="50"></a>

         <!-- watchlist -->

        <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex ">  
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id='navLink' href="./watchlist.html"> <img src="/images/food-07-512-removebg-preview.png" width="30" height="auto" class="d-inline-block align-bottom" alt=""> Your Watchlist</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I tried to add the `<a>` under `<ul>` as well, but it didn’t work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey i just tried your code it is working perfectly fine. It is linked correctly....when i clicked on links they took me to your github and linkedIn profile .

Comment: Thank you, Sanket. The probably must be something else then. I really appreciate you trying the code.

Comment: No problem . Always happy to help :)